# Google Sheets - Include Sheet Name in formula depending on string input

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet file with different sheets (e.g. "2018", "2019", "January_2018", "February_2018" and so on). In the sheet "2018", cell A1 is contains "January_2018", B2 contains "February_2018" etc.

I now want to include a formula in the cell "2018" A2 of that simply displays the value of cell A100 in the sheet with the name of cell "2018" A1 (in this case "January_2018").

The formula currently looks like this: ("2018" A2:) `=January_2018!$A$100` - the only problem is that I don't want to manually replace the "January_2018" with "February_2018" etc.
It should look something like - this is not working, otherwise I wouldn't ask this! - `=TEXT(A$1)!$A$100`. But I can't get it to work.

N.B.: I tried the `INDIRECT`-function but it doesn't do the trick - either because it's not the right formula, which I suspect, or because I didn't use it properly. I appreciate being pointed in the right direction. All the best and many thanks!
Ivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indirect formula is definitely what you want! It should be =indirect(A1&"!$A$100"). If the tab name has a space, it might have to be =indirect("'"&A1&"'!$A$100"). Let me know if that works for you!